# Using listings package, can I display line numberings in paretheses?

Tags: numbering, listings, line-numbering

I want to achieve the following effect for line numbers using lstlisting:

```
(1)  public constructor(value?: number) {
(2)    if (value > 0xff) {
(3)      throw new Error('Value should not be greater than 0xff');
(4)    }
(5)    this._intValue = value ? value & 0xff : 0;
(6)  }
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! This is possible by redefining the `\thelstnumber` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{(\the\value{lstnumber})} % <- add this to preamble

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\footnotesize, numbersep=5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
public constructor(value?: number) {
 if (value > 0xff) {
  throw new Error('Value should not be greater than 0xff');
 }
 this._intValue = value ? value & 0xff : 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]